# How to open offcanvas programmatically in Bootstrap 5?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-5

I have a bottom offcanvas in my webpage, i would open it on a card click, by trying to set the needed attributes or by using the code from the docs it's not working as the offcanvas shows only the backdrop and dismiss it immedialty.

Here is what i've tried:

```js
const products = document.getElementsByClassName("card product");

var productClick = function (event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    var myOffcanvas = document.getElementById('offcanvasBottom')
    var bsOffcanvas = new bootstrap.Offcanvas(myOffcanvas)
    bsOffcanvas.show();
};

Array.from(products).forEach(function (element) {
  element.addEventListener("click", productClick);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-JEW9xMcG8R+pH31jmWH6WWP0WintQrMb4s7ZOdauHnUtxwoG2vI5DkLtS3qm9Ekf" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="card product" style="width: 18rem">
  <div class="card-body text-center">
    <h2 class="card-title fw-bolder">TEST</h2>
    <p class="card-text fw-bolder">TEST</p>
  </div>
</div>

      <div
        class="offcanvas offcanvas-bottom"
        tabindex="-1"
        id="offcanvasBottom"
      >
        <div class="offcanvas-header">
          <button
            type="button"
            class="btn-close text-reset"
            data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas"
            aria-label="Close"
          ></button>
        </div>
        <div class="offcanvas-body">
         BODY
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: @ManasKhandelwal just added the snippet

Comment: Why are you using javascript? when you can do it with HTML?

Comment: @ManasKhandelwal - It should work with JavaScript and there may be many reasons for the not wanting to do it in HTML, for example many cards that are added dynamically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is the card click event is propagating to inside elements. Instead use `event.stopPropagation()`...

```js
const products = document.getElementsByClassName("product");
var myOffcanvas = document.getElementById('offcanvasBottom')
    
var productClick = function (event) {
    //event.preventDefault()
    event.stopPropagation()
    var bsOffcanvas = new bootstrap.Offcanvas(myOffcanvas)
    bsOffcanvas.show()
}

Array.from(products).forEach(function (element) {
    element.addEventListener("click", productClick);
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-JEW9xMcG8R+pH31jmWH6WWP0WintQrMb4s7ZOdauHnUtxwoG2vI5DkLtS3qm9Ekf" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="card product" style="width: 18rem">
  <div class="card-body text-center">
    <h2 class="card-title fw-bolder">TEST</h2>
    <p class="card-text fw-bolder">TEST</p>
  </div>
</div>

      <div
        class="offcanvas offcanvas-bottom"
        tabindex="-1"
        id="offcanvasBottom"
      >
        <div class="offcanvas-header">
          <button
            type="button"
            class="btn-close text-reset"
            data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas"
            aria-label="Close"
          ></button>
        </div>
        <div class="offcanvas-body">
         BODY
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add 'show' in the class of offcanvas

```
<div class="offcanvas offcanvase-bottom show"></div>
```

or use javascript to add class

```
<div class="offcanvas offcanvase-bottom show" id="off-id"></div>
<script>
    document.getElementById('off-id').classList.add('show')
</script>
```

Comment: If you have a backdrop canvas it won't work